# IndexError: list index out of range - While defining a 2d list

Tags: list, python-3.x

I'm trying to initialize a 2d list, when I run this code I get a "IndexError: list index out of range" error, why is this?

```
import numpy as np

cell_id = 0
obj_list = []

for i in range(0,100):
    for j in range(0,100):
        orient = np.random.randint(180)
        obj_list[i][j] = [cell_id, orient]
        cell_id += 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're declaring your list `obj_list = []` you have a list of things, but python doesn't know what they are supposed to be. When you do this `obj_list[i][j]` you're stating that the `i`th item in your list is an array, but you haven't yet explicitly stated that that's the case. So I would change your code to look like this:

```
for i in range(0,100):
    obj_list.append([]) # Append an element to the list
    for j in range(0,100):
        orient = np.random.randint(180)
        obj_list[i].append([cell_id, orient]) # append an element to the sub list
        cell_id += 1
```

Comment: @user3408085 whoops sorry - I corrected my answer. Was mentally lost in JavaScript land and forgot to fully convert over to python :)